# ScrollView doesn't stay to a certain part of the screen and takes whole screen

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, android-11

I am trying to limit my ScrollView to only a certain section of my screen as I am trying to attach a banner ad to the bottom of my screen and I want the banner ad to be static while the rest of the contents to be scroll-able therefore I don't want the banner ad to be affected by the ScrollView. For some reason though only the scroll-able section is visible on my device screen when I run my app, my banner ad does not show up at all. I have tried multiple methods to fix this problem to make it work and yet I still can't figure it out.
This is my current activity_main.xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@color/grey"
tools:context=".MainActivity">


<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
            app:cardElevation="8dp"
            app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/blue"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView
                android:id="@+id/search_view"
                app:defaultQueryHint="Search..."
                app:iconifiedByDefault="false"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"/>
        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView_a"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                android:text="A"
                android:textColor="@color/blue"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:textStyle="italic"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recycler_phonetics"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
            <TextView
                android:textSize="24sp"
                android:text="B"
                android:textColor="@color/blue"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:textStyle="italic"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recycler_meanings"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">
    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
</LinearLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, **never** use `RecyclerView` inside `Scrollview`. Instead, use `NestedScrollView`.

> NestedScrollView is just like ScrollView, but it supports acting as both a nested scrolling parent and child on both new and old versions of Android. Nested scrolling is enabled by default.

If you don't want your `RecyclerViews` too be scrollable in the first place, add your content as child views to a layout view.

Second, for your `ScrollView` to take up all the remaining space given by the `AdView`, craft a constraint chain and give the `ScrollView` a height of `0dp`. This means, you need to constrain the bottom of the `ScrollView` to the top of the `AdView` and vice versa.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
 ...>
    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/ScrollView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/LinearAdLayout">

        <!--Your content here-->

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/LinearAdLayout"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/ScrollView"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">
        
        <!--Your AdView here-->

    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```